# Processing Multidimensional JSON Array with PHP

Tags: php, json

This is the json that deepbit.net returns for my Bitcoin Miner worker.  I'm trying to access the workers array and loop through to print the stats for my myemail@gmail.com worker.  I can access the confirmed_reward, hashrate, ipa, and payout_history, but i'm having trouble formatting and outputting the workers array.

```
{
 "confirmed_reward":0.11895358,
 "hashrate":236.66666667,
 "ipa":true,
 "payout_history":0.6,
 "workers":
    {
      "myemail@gmail.com":
       {
         "alive":false,
         "shares":20044,
         "stales":51
       }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume you've decoded the string you gave with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) method, like...

```
$data = json_decode($json_string, TRUE);
```

To access the stats for the particular worker, just use...

```
$worker_stats = $data['workers']['myemail@gmail.com'];
```

To check whether it's alive, for example, you go with...

```
$is_alive = $worker_stats['alive'];
```

It's really that simple. )

Comment: Thanks man, json_decode($json_string, TRUE) did the trick. Second parameter did the magic!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`json_decode`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get an associative array from the JSON string.

In your example it would look something like:

```
$json = 'get yo JSON';
$array = json_decode($json, true); // The `true` says to parse the JSON into an array,
                                   // instead of an object.
foreach($array['workers']['myemail@gmail.com'] as $stat => $value) {
  // Do what you want with the stats
  echo "$stat: $value<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode).

You pass the string and it returns an object/array that you will use easily than the string directly.

To be more precise :

```
<?php
$aJson = json_decode('{"confirmed_reward":0.11895358,"hashrate":236.66666667,"ipa":true,"payout_history":0.6,"workers":{"myemail@gmail.com":{"alive":false,"shares":20044,"stales":51}}}');
$aJson['workers']['myemail@gmail.com']; // here's what you want!
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = json_decode($json, true); // true to return associative arrays
                                    // instead of objects

var_dump($result['workers']['myemail@gmail.com']);
```