# Printing json data

Tags: php, json

I have this json "https://www.decodethis.com/webservices/decodes/1Fmzu64p5yzb76700/aYcBzLfMCRs_JScq_sZt/0.json"
and I decode it with `$data = json_decode($json, true);`
But when I try to print the Vehicle part `foreach($data['vehicle'][0] as $p)
{echo $p;}`
the system prints
"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" and "Undefined index".
I'm a newbie, so forgive me.

Edit:
This worked very well `foreach ($data['decode']['vehicle'][0] as $p) echo $p;`, but now I wonder if I can know the key or index of the element $p on every loop, as example "body>driveline>engine>id"...

Comment: please search before you ask [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471592/processing-multidimensional-json-array-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to to use:

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://www.decodethis.com/webservices/decodes/1Fmzu64p5yzb76700/aYcBzLfMCRs_JScq_sZt/0.json");
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($obj["decode"]["vehicle"]  as $vehicle )
{
   echo $vehicle['body'];
   echo $vehicle['engine'];
   # etc...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the path is like these;

```
foreach ($data['decode']['vehicle'][0] as $p) echo $p;
```

Comment: And if I want the index of the element too?, as example: "body, SPORT UTILITY 4-DR"

Answer (score 0):

For accessing output in json file there is decode as root key. So first access decode key then after use vehicle information.

Below is code for that:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$json = $data["decode"]["vehicle"][0];
foreach($json->entries as $row) {
      foreach($row as $key => $val) { 
             echo $key . ': ' . $val;
             echo '<br>'; 
      }
}
```

Comment: The first foreach tells "Trying to get property of non-object", and also " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"