# Process item in a JSON nested array in a JSON nested array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Note that this is similar to [Processing Multidimensional JSON Array with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471592/processing-multidimensional-json-array-with-php), only with one caviot.

I have a JSON with a few arrays from the following taken from Airtable (URLs censored)

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "id": "RECORD_ID",
            "fields": {
                "Name": "Setsuna Meioh",
                "Birthday": "2020-10-29",
                "Gender": "Female",
                "Series": "Sailor Moon",
                "Picture": [
                    {
                        "id": "this_is_id1",
                        "url": "http://IMAGE.URL",
                        "filename": "IMAGE_FILENAME",
                        "size": 97060,
                        "type": "image/png",
                        "thumbnails": {
                            "small": {
                                "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/THUMBNAIL_SMAL_URL",
                                "width": 34,
                                "height": 36
                            },
                            "large": {
                                "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/THUMBNAIL_LARGE_URL",
                                "width": 295,
                                "height": 317
                            },
                            "full": {
                                "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/THUMBNAIL_FULL_URL",
                                "width": 3000,
                                "height": 3000
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "RECORD_ID2",
            "fields": {
                "Name": "Rin Hoshizora",
                "Birthday": "2020-11-01",
                "Gender": "Female",
                "Series": "Love Live (School Idol Project)",
                "Picture": [
                    {
                        "id": "this_is_id2",
                        "url": "http://IMAGE.URL",
                        "filename": "IMAGE_FILENAME",
                        "size": 131749,
                        "type": "image/png",
                        "thumbnails": {
                            "small": {
                                "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/THUMBNAIL_SMAL_URL",
                                "width": 34,
                                "height": 36
                            },
                            "large": {
                                "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/THUMBNAIL_LARGE_URL",
                                "width": 295,
                                "height": 317
                            },
                            "full": {
                                "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/THUMBNAIL_FULL_URL",
                                "width": 3000,
                                "height": 3000
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to access the `url` item in a Picture array, and I already have the `jsonDecode` method already set up from a cURL response.

Now, I already know how to use the brackets `[]` when it's accessing a array (as shown on the link above), but the problem is, there is **another** array in a array.

What I did was using a longer string to get to a array.

```
echo $data->records[0]->fields->Picture[0]->thumbnails->small->url;
```

I tried that, but unfortunately came out nothing. Then I tried another method below

```
$Image1Base = $data->records[0]->fields->Picture[0];
$Image1URL = $Image1Base->url;

// then the echo

echo $Image1URL
```

Came out nothing either. Is there something missing?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, https://3v4l.org/lpJeb

Comment: Try to set second parameter of `json_decode` to true to get an associative array. It will be much easier for you. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

It works.

Check if there are other errors.

Whether some expected structure does not exist in the real data.

% cat test4.php

```
<?php
$jsonStr =
'{
    "records": [
        {
            "id": "RECORD_ID",
            "fields": {
                "Name": "Setsuna Meioh",
                "Birthday": "2020-10-29",
                "Gender": "Female",
                "Series": "Sailor Moon",
                "Picture": [
                    {
                        "id": "this_is_id1",
                        "url": "http://IMAGE.URL",
                        "filename": "IMAGE_FILENAME",
                        "size": 97060,
                        "type": "image/png",
                        "thumbnails": {
                            "small": {
                                "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/THUMBNAIL_SMAL_URL",
                                "width": 34,
                                "height": 36
                            },
                            "large": {
                                "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/THUMBNAIL_LARGE_URL",
                                "width": 295,
                                "height": 317
                            },
                            "full": {
                                "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/THUMBNAIL_FULL_URL",
                                "width": 3000,
                                "height": 3000
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "RECORD_ID2",
            "fields": {
                "Name": "Rin Hoshizora",
                "Birthday": "2020-11-01",
                "Gender": "Female",
                "Series": "Love Live (School Idol Project)",
                "Picture": [
                    {
                        "id": "this_is_id2",
                        "url": "http://IMAGE.URL",
                        "filename": "IMAGE_FILENAME",
                        "size": 131749,
                        "type": "image/png",
                        "thumbnails": {
                            "small": {
                                "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/THUMBNAIL_SMAL_URL",
                                "width": 34,
                                "height": 36
                            },
                            "large": {
                                "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/THUMBNAIL_LARGE_URL",
                                "width": 295,
                                "height": 317
                            },
                            "full": {
                                "url": "https://dl.airtable.com/THUMBNAIL_FULL_URL",
                                "width": 3000,
                                "height": 3000
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}';

$data = json_decode($jsonStr);
$Image1Base = $data->records[0]->fields->Picture[0];
$Image1URL = $Image1Base->url;
var_dump($Image1URL);
```

% php -S localhost:8001

```
view-source:http://localhost:8001/test4.php


string(16) "http://IMAGE.URL"
```